# code refactoring, in order to get rid of code duplication

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following class structure:

```
public class Result
{
   protected int Code {get; set;}
   protected List<string> Messages {get; set;} 
   protected Result ();

   public static Result Success (int code, List<string> messages)
   {
    Result result= new Result();
    result.Code=code;
    result.Messages=messages;
    return result;
   }

}

public class ResultWithName: Result
{
  protected ID {get; set;}

  protected ResultWithName ()
  {
  }

  public static ResultWithName Success (int code, List<string> messages, string name)
  {
    ResultWithName result= new ResultWithName();
    result.Code=code;
    result.Messages=messages;
    result.Name=name;
    return result;
  }

}
```

The problem would be ok if there is only one static method, but there are several ones, and I am interested how to have a more cleaner elegant code.
Thanks

Comment: The "cleaner more elegant code" is simply to not use a static method at all.

Comment: I'm not certain we're looking at all the code. He's protected the constructor, which means the Success method is a factory. In that case, it's perfectly acceptable for it to be a static method. (Though I wouldn't have expected it to be so given the name.)

Comment: @Billy - that's a Factory Method, which is perfectly respectable

Comment: @Steve: In that code there is no reason to use a factory method. What is being done there should be dine in a constructor instead.

Comment: @Billy - if this is the entire source code, I agree.  Often these qs are to aid understanding design issues in a larger context, though.  It's not reasonable imo to ask people to post minimally sufficient code, and then tell them it's too simple for a pattern to be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define your constructors with parameters instead of setting the properties inline in the `Success` methods.  Then set the properties in the constructor as each is invoked down the inheritance chain.

```
public class Result
{
    protected int Code { get; set; }
    protected List<string> Messages { get; set; }
    protected Result(int code, List<string> messages)
    {
        Code = code;
        Messages = messages;
    }

    public static Result Success(int code, List<string> messages)
    {
        Result result = new Result(code, messages);
        return result;
    }

}

public class ResultWithName : Result
{
    protected string Name { get; set; }

    protected ResultWithName(int code, List<string> messages, string name) :
        base(code, messages)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public static ResultWithName Success(int code, List<string> messages, string name)
    {
        ResultWithName result = new ResultWithName(code, messages, name);
        return result;
    }

}
```